# Were there 'voting irregularities' in early Utah history?

Tags: united-states

I'm reading excerpts from *Among the Mormons*, which is a collection of primary-source documents regarding Utah history from the Mormon migration to, roughly, the Great Depression.

One of the pieces details an election where a coordinated effort among the 'Gentiles' caused large numbers of ballots to be tossed into rivers, while railroad workers voted many, many, times in numerous precincts.

I've looked through a few textbooks, but I haven't found anything that describes this.  I'm wondering if this actually happened and was simply excluded from texts, or is it just a myth?

Comment: I would suspect, in my cynical old age, that there are "voting irregularities" *any* time you have voting; the real issue is whether those irregularities are sufficient to change the winner.  Fortunately, this question seems to address the real issue; +1 from me.  (Although, if you have a collection of primary-source documents, what are you looking for as proof?)

Comment: There is only one account of the event in the anthology - and there isn't much detail about it either.  A second primary account or research from historians would be very helpful.

(Edit, Sorry, I didn't realize "enter" submitted..)

Comment: I agree with your skepticism. One thing we've seen over the past few years is that people who lose an election are quite capable of inventing non-existent "voting irregularities", rather than admit they got outvoted and need to do better next time. So I wouldn't 100% trust a report of fraud that is only sourced from the losers.

Comment: This was not recent.  The anthology was published in the fifties with the foreward on this article being that it was roughly thirty years old.  So the latest this would've happened is the twenties, roughly...